# Keep screen on from a service

Tags: android, service, timeout, screen, wakelock

I would like to know how to keep the screen permanently on from a service. Here is the scenario for the code:
User plugs phone into power outlet,
Broadcast receiver gets event, start a service that prevent the screen from timing out.
User unplugs phone, service is killed and timeout restored.

I wanted to use wakelocks but the level that is needed is deprecated in API 13:

> int SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK This constant was deprecated in API level
>   13. Most applications should use FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON instead of this type of wake lock, as it will be correctly managed by the platform as
>   the user moves between applications and doesn't require a special
>   permission.

`FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` cannot be used from a service from what I've read.

I don't want to modify the screen timeout number since if my service is destroyed or application uninstalled, I don't want the timeout to be stuck at a high number.

Also my application cannot get any system permission so anything requiring *`DEVICE_POWER` permission*, I can't use

Any idea?
Thanks for any insight,
Amish

Comment: do not forget to accept an answer or answer your own question and accept it later.

Answer (score 1):

deprecated **doesn't mean you can't use** it in for versions greater than 13.
if you're minimum required version is let's say 8 (not confirmed), you have no other option. The wake lock is still available in api level 17.

Comment: Oh did not know that. Well I will try the wakelock then. Thanks